# Web editing background - getting accredited in coding

Tags: html, sharepoint

I have a background in intranet/Web content management, mostly in SharePoint. My current job requires a pretty sound knowledge of HTML and I've managed to get to grips with the essential points but would really like some proper training and possibly accreditation. I'd really like to learn more about programming and CSS but think I really need my ducks in a row on this first (but happy to be proved wrong!!) There are a lot of courses out there and I wondered if there were any some might recommend. I'm after part time study and don't have a huge wad of cash to throw at this unfortunately. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/  have great courses. A basic plan is $25.

Answer (score 0):

There are many pages to learn HTML, CSS, ...
Google will list much more than we could ever post here.
Please do some research.

But have a look:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/

https://www.codeschool.com/learn/html-css

...

Comment: Thanks both, that's really helpful. Nick I realise Google has a wealth of information but I'm more interested in courses/accreditations.